# Jquery form validator does not work

Tags: jquery

I am using this site http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html to test out my live form validation. The problem I am having is that the codes are not working at all.

Here is the html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <p>
        User name (4 characters minimum, only alphanumeric characters):
        <input data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min4">
      </p>
      <p>
        Year (yyyy-mm-dd):
        <input data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      </p>
      <p>
        Website:
        <input data-validation="url">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit">
      </p>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $.validate({
        lang: 'es'
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me after I created a snippet from your code. Try it here?

Comment: You need to add the protocol when you are testing from your local harddrive

Comment: @mplungjan It does not work for me, even after fixing the script tags with http

Comment: You can try to use https - what are the console errors? (press F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not linking the scripts correctly you are omitting the http:// or https:// it's important if you are running it in your localhost.

I tested it and it's working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <p>
            User name (4 characters minimum, only alphanumeric characters):
            <input data-validation="length alphanumeric" data-validation-length="min4">
          </p>
          <p>
            Year (yyyy-mm-dd):
            <input data-validation="date" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
          </p>
          <p>
            Website:
            <input data-validation="url">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit">
          </p>
        </form>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $.validate({
            lang: 'es'
          });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code, still does not work, I am not sure whats going on, I just made a file validation.html and pasted your code....

Comment: You are not completely correct. She needs to add the protocol when testing from file system. From server it is better to omit the http since the server will add the relevant protocol

Comment: it depends whether she is trying it from her localhost or not.

Comment: Yes, that is what I just said - localhost will also add http. The error is when you test from hard disc using file://

Comment: @EnmanuelDurán its working now after I put https !!!! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mplungjan  its working now after putting https! THANKS ALOT

Comment: @Aurora Great, I just updated my answer in order to make it more understandable to others that could pass through this.